# Multiple tables (5) on one page using ReportLab

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I have the following code in Python to generate two tables using ReportLab.

Is there a way to position these two tables side by side using ReportLab?

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table_grid.pdf", pagesize=letter)
elements = []

data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04','10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
   ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
   ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
   ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14']]
   
t=Table(data,5*[0.3*inch], 4*[0.2*inch])
t.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(4,0),colors.gray),
                   ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ]))

elements.append(t)

data= [['100', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
   ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
   ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
   ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
   
t=Table(data,5*[0.3*inch], 4*[0.2*inch])
t.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(4,0),colors.gray),
                   ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ]))

elements.append(t)

doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: Have you tried using frames? You could position 2 frames next to each other, and either tweak the table width to fill each frame (so it forces reportlab to draw in the next one), or manually append a FrameBreak to go into the next one. I should be able to work out an example later tonight if no one else answers by then.

Answer (score 6):

Create a third table that will serve as the shell for the two tables you created.  This table will have two columns and one row.  Each column will be the size of the respective child table.

Example:

*create your two tables in different table vars (e.g. **table1**, **table2**)*

```
t1_w = <your first table width size>
t2_w = <your second table width size>
data = [[table1, table2]]
shell_table = Table(data, colWidths=[t1_w, t2_w])
```

Answer (score 4):

Example:
*whole code

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table_grid.pdf", pagesize=letter)
elements = []

data1 = [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
        ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
        ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
        ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14']]

t1 = Table(data1, 5 * [0.3 * inch], 4 * [0.2 * inch])
t1.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (4, 0), colors.gray),
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
]))


data2 = [['100', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
        ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
        ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
        ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]

t2 = Table(data2, 5 * [0.4 * inch], 4 * [0.2 * inch])
t2.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (4, 0), colors.gray),
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
]))

data = [[t1, t2]]
# adjust the length of tables
t1_w = 3 * inch
t2_w = 3 * inch
shell_table = Table(data, colWidths=[t1_w, t2_w])
elements.append(shell_table)
doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: works great, but can't get an image and paragraph on same line